# Spinning animation while another process is running in pyqt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I have a simple pyqt5 application that reads big *.json file and makes a treelist view of keys.
Would like to know how to make a simultaneous work of animation and relatively long json reading task.
So I need a wheel to be spinning while file is reading.

Looks like it has to be a threading but I am not familiar with it yet.

Here is a code:

```
import sys 
import os 
import json
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,  QGridLayout, QLabel, QListView, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
load_icon = os.path.join(current_folder, 'icon_load.png')

class loaderDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ren_loaderDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()


    def get_values_dict(self):
        """Getting data of unique values using in tables
        and making a dict of mappings for specific table
        Operation can take a long time
        """

        script_folder = current_folder
        file_local = os.path.join(script_folder, 'attributes.json')

        with open(file_local, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)

        return data


    def initUI(self):
        """Set GUI and get all data for launching
        """

        self.setWindowTitle('Layer loader')
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 400, 520)

        self.listView = QTreeWidget()
        self.listView.setHeaderLabel('Layers')

        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.listView, 0, 1, 1, 2)

        self.case_strings = self.get_values_dict()
        self.load_data_to_tree(self.case_strings)

        self.show()


    def loading_fig(self):
        """Animation of rotating wheel
        """

        self.spin_wheel_init = QLabel()
        self.spin_wheel_init.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spin_wheel_init.setPixmap(QPixmap(load_icon))
        self.grid.addWidget(self.spin_wheel_init, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        angle = 0

        while True:
            tr = QTransform().rotate(angle)
            angle = angle + 1 if angle<360 else 0
            self.spin_wheel_init.setPixmap(QPixmap(load_icon).transformed(tr))
            time.sleep(0.001)
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()


    def load_data_to_tree(self, data):
        """Giving keys to treeview
        """
        for name in data:
            child = QTreeWidgetItem(self.listView)
            child.setFlags(child.flags() | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            child.setText(0, name)
            child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = loaderDialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here I need to make funtion `loading_fig` working while file is reading in function called `get_values_dict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid to use loops and `sleep` in you UI thread.

A common way to run a long time function is to create another thread. You can do it with `QThread` Qt class (or in Python if you prefer).

To use `QThread`, create a new class `Worker` inheriting from `QObject`. It will contain your process. Then, create an instance and *move* it to another thread:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    done = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def doWork(self):
        print("Start")
        time.sleep(10)
        self.done.emit(['one', 'two', 'three'])
        print("done")
```

```
class loaderDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(loaderDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.thread = QThread(self)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread) # worker will be runned in another thread
        self.worker.done.connect(self.load_data_to_tree) # Call load_data_to_tree when worker.done is emitted
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.doWork) # Call worker.doWork when the thread starts
        self.thread.start() # Start the thread (and run doWork)
```

For the spinner, you should use an animation such as `QPropertyAnimation` instead of a loop. For example:

```
class Spinner(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(load_icon)

        self.setFixedSize(30, 30)
        self._angle = 0

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"angle", self)
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(360)
        self.animation.setLoopCount(-1)
        self.animation.setDuration(2000)
        self.animation.start()


    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def angle(self):
        return self._angle

    @angle.setter
    def angle(self, value):
        self._angle = value
        self.update()


    def paintEvent(self, ev=None):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.translate(15, 15)
        painter.rotate(self._angle)
        painter.translate(-15, -15)
        painter.drawPixmap(5, 5, self.pixmap)
```

Comment: as far as I understood I need also create another thread for `Spinner` class to run it while `Worker` do its job?

Comment: You don't need to: `QPropertyAnimation` will use the event loop to update the spinner.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to move the animation to a new thread, rather than the worker?